# Foreign Key becomes unique while migrating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

This one is the main employee table entity, while migrating the foreign key becomes unique and not allowing duplicate value in the table.

I need to add multiple data for a single employee in the `exitdetail` entity so I am creating a foreign key reference from employee table to the `ExitDetailEntity` table, but the foreign key becoming a unique key while migrating and not allowing duplicates.

```
public class EmployeeDetailEntity : Entity
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(12)]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(64)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(256)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(64)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This table has a foreign key ref from EmployeeDetail

```
public class ExitDetailEntity : Entity
{
    public int EmployeeDetailId {get; set; }
    public EmployeeDetailEntity EmployeeDetail {get; set; }

    public ExitStatusEnum ExitStatus {get; set;}
}
```

This table has a reference from ExitDetil table

```
public class ExitDetailAdminEntity : Entity
{
    public int ExitDetailId {get; set; }
    public ExitDetailEntity ExitDetail {get; set; }

    public bool HasTaskCompleted {get; set;}
}
```

This is the enum referred to in exitdetail

```
public enum ExitStatusEnum
{
   Active = 0,
   Resigned = 1,
   Requested = 2,
   Cancelled = 3

}
```

This is the migration command for the exitdetailentity table

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ExitDetail",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                CreatedBy = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 32, nullable: false),
                CreatedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                ModifiedBy = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 32, nullable: true),
                ModifiedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                RowVersion = table.Column<byte[]>(rowVersion: true, nullable: true),
                IsDeleted = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                EmployeeDetailId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                RequestStatus = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                ApprovalStatus = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ExitDetail", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_ExitDetail_EmployeeDetail_EmployeeDetailId",
                    column: x => x.EmployeeDetailId,
                    principalTable: "EmployeeDetail",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

This is the line where the unique index is becoming true

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_ExitDetail_EmployeeDetailId",
            table: "ExitDetail",
            column: "EmployeeDetailId",
            unique: true);
```

Here is the code inside my onmodelcreating method

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<LocationCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DivisionCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TeamCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<FunctionCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DesignationCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<LevelCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ShiftCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<RegularizationTypeCodeTable>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeDetailEntity>().HasQueryFilter(x => !x.IsDeleted);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<EmployeeDetailEntity>()
            .HasOne(x => x.ManagerRef)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<EmployeeDetailEntity>()
            .HasIndex(x => x.EmployeeId)
            .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder
           .Entity<EmployeeDetailEntity>()
           .HasIndex(x => x.DomainName);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add code of migration that makes foreign keys unique?

Comment: @Alexander sorry , this error is something that happened in my work, and I dont have the migration code, will provide it by once I get there, Is there any modification that I have to make in this code

Comment: Tell me please what properties `Entity` holds and I'll check what's wrong

Comment: I've created migration with these entities and everything is fine for me. Do you have entity configurations?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Alexander, only these are the properties the entities hold, while migrating the EmpoyeeDetailEntity reference in the ExitDetailEntity is becoming a unique key and not accepting any duplicate value

Comment: No Even I have created migrations before they work fine, but in this case the foreign key reference is becoming unique, Is there any way to remove the unique index

Comment: Well EF always creates indexes for foreign keys but they usually are not unique. As I said I created migration and I have `CreateIndex` code but wihout `unique` set to `true`

Comment: I am using azure sql, one thing that I am sure is in the migration code there is not specific command that sets the foreign key to be unique, only in the db its getting created as unique, while trying to write in the db I am getting the error in the final savechanges command

Comment: @ninja_2509 The FKs do **not** become unique by default and w/o a reason. We need to see you model **fluent configuration** - for instance, if it contains `HasOne` + `WithOne`.

Comment: @Alexander,  Ivan Stoev  I have added the migration command for the exitdetailentity table,

Comment: @ninja_2509 And in what line of migration `unique` is set?

Comment: @Alexander added the complete data of what happened in the migration, sorry I didn't add this one earlier

Comment: @ninja_2509 Thanks, I see. One more thing, are you using special azure sql provider for EF? If yes, tell me please how you added it so I can test migrations against it.

Comment: yes, I am using azure sql, but I didnt create it my manager did, its requires an azure subscription, you can add it in azure's resource group

Comment: @ninja_2509 We don't need the generated migration. The point was that the migration is generated based on your model (entity classes + data annotations + fluent configuration). We need to see the code inside  `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have added my onmodelcreating method, kindly check and provide a response if you figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need define a primary key for each related entities, for example:

```
public class ExitDetailEntity : Entity
{
    public int Id {get; set; } //primary key
    public int EmployeeDetailId {get; set; }
    public EmployeeDetailEntity EmployeeDetail {get; set; }
    public ExitStatusEnum ExitStatus {get; set;}
}
```

Then all the other properties will not be unique.

You can see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys

Comment: the entity that I extended has the Id property, So its has a primary key